# Android SDK and AVD Manager hangs trying to rename temporary folders

Tags: android

I run Android SDK and AVD Manager in Vista and have problems installing components. The installer downloads components successfully, but at the end of the installation it hangs for about minute and then asks to disable AV software. If I choose 'No', the installer stops with error message like: "Filed to rename directory '...' to '...' ". Thus, I have to unpack downloaded components and place them to proper folders manually.

I have no AV software. I assumed that the installer requires Administrator rights, but runing it as Administrator didn't help.

If anybody fixed the issue, please advice something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on Windows 7 32-bit. It worked eventually for me. Disabling your AV has no effect. It's probably a zombie copy of the manager.

Exit Eclipse etc... 
Close most other apps, Run eclipse, run the manager (you have to click on the menu twice for some reason), I eventually got it installed OK on my 3rd attempt - just try again.